# MVC: Why is my Edit controller method not receiving my ViewModel's ID?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, razor

I am using MVC to create standard create / edit forms for my ViewModel. I have my create working great, now I'm onto my edit form, and the ViewModel's ID is being passed as 0, even though I can see the DOM Element explorer (& web UI) that ID is set to 10004. I tried binding all the fields to my [HttpPost] Edit controller method, but the ID remains 0. Any ideas?

Here's a snippet of my code (I have too many fields, etc to post everything, and all other fields are coming across correctly).

Thanks in advance!

**ViewModel**

```
public class Header_VM
    {           
        [DisplayName("Contract ID")]
        public int Contract_Key { get; set; }

        etc
    }
```

**View**

```
@model (root).Header.Header_VM

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Edit Header: @Model.Name</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Header", FormMethod.Post, new { name = "EditForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal" ng-app="HeaderApp">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Contract_Key, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Contract_Key)
        </div>
        etc...
    </div>
}
```

I have a break point on "int NewID...", and at that point Contract_Key is 0.

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Contract_Key, etc...")] Header_VM header)
{
     int NewID = DB.Header_Insert(header);
     return RedirectToAction("Details", "Header", new { Contract_Key = NewID });
 }
```

Comment: You have not created a form control for `Contract_Key` (`DisplayFor()` just create text, not an input)

Comment: Yes, because its an ID. The users are not allowed to edit this field.

Comment: Your controller cannot set the property if you never send it to the controller! (and why are using `LabelFor()` if you do not create an associated control). You need a hidden input, or better, add the value as a route parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DisplayFor` helper method generates HTML markup to **display** the property value. So if you inspect the page source(view source), you will see markup for a `label` tag for the Contract_Key property. When you submit the form, only input form field values are submitted , not label/div values

You need an input form field inside your form with name attribute value set to `"Contract_Key"`.

You can use the `HiddenFor` helper method, which generates a hidden input element with the name attribute value matching to the property name.

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Contract_Key)
 @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Contract_Key)
```

Or simply a hand written hidden input

```
<input type="hidden" name="Contract_Key" value="@Model.Contract_Key" />
```

Comment: Don't you think this is a dangerous approach? Users can edit this by pressing F12.