# Why one hidden view change not showing after leave form page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I found out that my index page wasn't showing the updated user info for currently logged in user.  So I changed the form page **from:**

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SubmittedDate, new { Value = System.DateTime.Now })            
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SubmittedBy, new { Value = Model.ADAccount })
        </div>
    </div>

**to:**
<div class="col-xs-4">
       <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SubmittedDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })     
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SubmittedBy, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UpdatedDate, new { Value = System.DateTime.Now })
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UpdateBy, new { htmlAttributes = new { Value = Model.ADAccount } })
        </div>
    </div>
```

I had also tried changing the form page like this but it didn't change anything:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UpdateBy, new { Value = Model.ADAccount })
```

The submit looks like this in the form page:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Button()
                                .Name("submit")
                                .Content("Submit")
                                .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "k-primary" })
                                .Events(ev => ev.Click("onClick")))
```

But for some reason it's still not showing the UpdateBy in the Index list.  I don't see a specific reference in the Controller for UpdateBy or SubmittedBy.  I see them both in the ApplicantCapturedData.cs list:

```
public string UpdateBy { get; set; }
public string SubmittedBy { get; set; }
```

I see in ApplicantController.cs, the Edit Post puts some data in the DB, but doesn't mention the updateBy or SubmittedBy variables or model specifically. However, in the old code, the SubmittedBy variable change did show on the index list. I looked in the project, and there are no specific references to SubmittedBy besides ApplicantController

When I put a watch on UpdateBy, I see it go back and forth between the old user, me, and null.  Apparently it ends with the old user, because that's what is displayed in the list of applicants on the index after the form is submitted.

Any thoughts on how to fix this?  I'm new to MVC, and I'm not sure why this change isn't getting back to the model/db.  When the applicantController gets the applicantCapturedData, it shows the old value for UpdateBy, not the new value.

The Edit Method should return current loged-in user to the view instead of BD data, but it's not. I'm not sure why.

I looked at [controller not receiving model info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42963322/mvc-why-is-my-edit-controller-method-not-receiving-my-viewmodels-id), but it didn't seem like the same issue to me.

Let me know if you think I'm leaving any crucial info out that you need.  I obviously can't post all of the mvc files and code here for clarity and sanity.

******Update*********
This is the Edit/Post method in ApplicantController.cs. It doesn't specifically refer to the SubmittedBy or UpdateBy, but the SubmittedBy part does show up in the index, even when we updated it in the form with current AD user:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(ApplicantCapturedData applicantCapturedData)
{
    var eRecordSchedulinglist = applicantCapturedData.ERecordScheduling;
    var eRecordScheduling = new ERecordScheduling();

    // int IDs = applicantCapturedData.ID;
    //updating Provider License 
    var providerLicenselist = applicantCapturedData.ProviderLicense;
    var providerLicense = new ProviderLicense();

    var eprescribelist = applicantCapturedData.EPrescribe;
    var eprescribe = new EPrescribe();
    //updating payor table 
    var payorlist = applicantCapturedData.Payor;
    var payor = new Payor();

    //updating tax table 
    var taxlist = applicantCapturedData.TaxNPITaxonomy;
    var tax = new TaxNPITaxonomy();
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //ERecordScheduling eRecordScheduling = new ERecordScheduling();
        db.Entry(applicantCapturedData).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();

        int getid = applicantCapturedData.ID;

        //Getting values for provider license already in db
        var query = from p in db.ProviderLicenses
                    where p.ApplicantCapturedData_ID == getid
                    select p;

        //deleting the existing rows
        foreach (var i in query)
        {
            db.ProviderLicenses.Remove(i);
        }
        db.SaveChanges();

        int c = 1;
        if (providerLicenselist != null)
        {

            var updatePLS = providerLicenselist.ToList();
            // adding only new record to db
            foreach (var i in updatePLS)
            {
                providerLicense.LicenseNumber = i.LicenseNumber;
                providerLicense.State = i.State;
                providerLicense.ProviderLicenseID = i.ProviderLicenseID;
                i.ApplicantCapturedData_ID = getid;


                if (providerLicense.ProviderLicenseID <= c)
                {
                    providerLicense.ProviderLicenseID = providerLicense.ProviderLicenseID++;
                }

                db.ProviderLicenses.Add(i);
                db.SaveChanges();

            }
        }
        //getting  Values already existing in db for Erecording Schedulign
        var queryERS = from p in db.ERecordSchedulings
                       where p.ApplicantCapturedData_ID == getid
                       select p;


        //deleting the existing rows
        foreach (var i in queryERS)
        {
            db.ERecordSchedulings.Remove(i);
        }
        db.SaveChanges();

        if (eRecordSchedulinglist != null)
        {
            var updateESCH = eRecordSchedulinglist.ToList();
            foreach (var item in updateESCH)
            {
                eRecordScheduling.DepartmentName = item.DepartmentName;
                eRecordScheduling.Shedules = item.Shedules;
                eRecordScheduling.VisitType = item.VisitType;
                eRecordScheduling.GenericProvider = item.GenericProvider;
                eRecordScheduling.ERecordSchedulingID = item.ERecordSchedulingID;
                // a.ApplicantCapturedData_ID = newid;
                item.ApplicantCapturedData_ID = getid;

                if (eRecordScheduling.ERecordSchedulingID <= c)
                {
                    eRecordScheduling.ERecordSchedulingID = eRecordScheduling.ERecordSchedulingID++;
                }

                //save to db
                db.ERecordSchedulings.Add(item);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        //Getting Values that already exisit in db for Taxonomy 
        var querytaxo = from p in db.TaxNPITaxonomies
                        where p.ApplicantCapturedData_ID == getid
                        select p;

        //deleting the existing rows
        foreach (var i in querytaxo)
        {
            db.TaxNPITaxonomies.Remove(i);
        }
        db.SaveChanges();

        if (taxlist != null)
        {
            var UpdateTaxo = taxlist.ToList();
            foreach (var t in UpdateTaxo)
            {
                tax.GroupNPI = t.GroupNPI;
                tax.Notes = t.Notes;
                tax.TaxID = t.TaxID;
                tax.TaxNPITaxonomyID = t.TaxNPITaxonomyID;
                tax.Taxonomy = t.TaxID;
                t.ApplicantCapturedData_ID = getid;

                if (tax.TaxNPITaxonomyID <= c)
                {
                    tax.TaxNPITaxonomyID = tax.TaxNPITaxonomyID++;
                }

                db.TaxNPITaxonomies.Add(t);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        var queryeprescribe = from p in db.EPrescribes
                              where p.ApplicantCapturedData_ID == getid
                              select p;

        foreach (var i in queryeprescribe)
        {
            db.EPrescribes.Remove(i);
        }
        db.SaveChanges();

        if (eprescribelist != null)
        {
            var updateeprescribe = eprescribelist.ToList();

            foreach (var t in updateeprescribe)
            {
                eprescribe.EPrescribeOptions = t.EPrescribeOptions;
                eprescribe.ID = t.ID;
                t.ApplicantCapturedData_ID = getid;
                if (eprescribe.ApplicantCapturedData_ID <= c)
                {
                    eprescribe.ApplicantCapturedData_ID = eprescribe.ApplicantCapturedData_ID++;
                }
                db.EPrescribes.Add(t);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

        }

        //Geting values that already exist in db for Payors

        var queryPayor = from p in db.Payors
                         where p.ApplicantCapturedData_ID == getid
                         select p;

        //deleting the existing rows
        foreach (var i in queryPayor)
        {
            db.Payors.Remove(i);
        }
        db.SaveChanges();

        if (payorlist != null)
        {
            var updatepayor = payorlist.ToList();

            foreach (var p in updatepayor)
            {
                payor.Pyor = p.Pyor;
                payor.PayorID = p.PayorID;

                p.ApplicantCapturedData_ID = getid;

                if (payor.PayorID <= c)
                {
                    payor.PayorID = payor.PayorID++;
                }

                db.Payors.Add(p);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }

    return View(applicantCapturedData);
}
```

Here's the save in ApplicantController.cs. It doesn't have a specific reference to UpdateBy or SubmittedBy either, and yet SubmittedBy used to update when I changed the AD user:

```
//  [HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(ApplicantCapturedData applicantCapturedData)
{
     ViewBag.PostedBills = applicantCapturedData.BillingAreas;

    applicantCapturedData.BillingAreas = applicantCapturedData.BillingAreas;

    //updating eRecordScheduling 
    var list = applicantCapturedData.ERecordScheduling;
    var a = new ERecordScheduling();
    var OtherAddressList = applicantCapturedData.PracticeInfoOtherLocations;
    var otheraddresses = new PracticeInfoOtherLocation();

    //var payorlist = applicantCapturedData.Payor;
    //var payor = new Payor();
    // int IDs = applicantCapturedData.ID;
    //updating Provider License 

    var providerLicenselist = applicantCapturedData.ProviderLicense;
    var providerLicense = new ProviderLicense();

    var Eprescribelist = applicantCapturedData.EPrescribe;
    var eprescribe = new EPrescribe();

    //updating payor table 
    var payorlist = applicantCapturedData.Payor;
    var payor = new Payor();

    //updating tax table 
    var taxlist = applicantCapturedData.TaxNPITaxonomy;
    var tax = new TaxNPITaxonomy();

    //   var lastEnt = db.ERecordSchedulings.AsEnumerable().Where(i => i.ERecordSchedulingID.CompareTo(a.ERecordSchedulingID))
    int c = 1;//lastEnter.LastOrDefault().ERecordSchedulingID;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.ApplicantCapturedDatas.Add(applicantCapturedData);
        //  db.ERecordSchedulings.Add(applicantCapturedData);
        db.SaveChanges();
        //db.ERecordSchedulings.Add(applicantCapturedData.ERecordScheduling);

        //get the primary key id after adding to the Db
        int newid = applicantCapturedData.ID;

        if (applicantCapturedData.ERecordScheduling != null)
        {
            //  check if we have more record on Erecord scheduling using the count
            //if count is greater than zero we have record to add to db.
            if (applicantCapturedData.ERecordScheduling.Count() > 0)
            {
                /*
                 * This loops thru the list and add record 
                 * 
                 */
                foreach (var item in list)
                {

                    a.DepartmentName = item.DepartmentName;
                    a.Shedules = item.Shedules;
                    a.VisitType = item.VisitType;
                    a.GenericProvider = item.GenericProvider;
                    a.ERecordSchedulingID = item.ERecordSchedulingID;
                    // a.ApplicantCapturedData_ID = newid;
                    item.ApplicantCapturedData_ID = newid;


                    //if you put a breakpoint at the beginning of this class you will see that all id is 0 I had to increment the id so I don't override itself.
                    if (a.ERecordSchedulingID <= c)
                    {
                        a.ERecordSchedulingID = a.ERecordSchedulingID++;
                    }

                    //save to db
                    db.ERecordSchedulings.Add(item);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    //item.LicenseNumber = a.LicenseNumber;
                    //item.State = a.State;
                    //item.ProviderLicenseID = a.ProviderLicenseID;
                }


            }
        }

        if (applicantCapturedData.ProviderLicense != null)
        {
            if (applicantCapturedData.ProviderLicense.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (var i in providerLicenselist)
                {
                    providerLicense.LicenseNumber = i.LicenseNumber;
                    providerLicense.State = i.State;
                    providerLicense.ProviderLicenseID = i.ProviderLicenseID;
                    i.ApplicantCapturedData_ID = newid;


                    if (providerLicense.ProviderLicenseID <= c)
                    {
                        providerLicense.ProviderLicenseID = providerLicense.ProviderLicenseID++;
                    }

                    db.ProviderLicenses.Add(i);
                    db.SaveChanges();

                }
            }
        }

        if (applicantCapturedData.Payor != null)
        {
            if (applicantCapturedData.Payor.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (var p in payorlist)
                {
                    payor.Pyor = p.Pyor;
                    payor.PayorID = p.PayorID;

                    p.ApplicantCapturedData_ID = newid;

                    if (payor.PayorID <= c)
                    {
                        payor.PayorID = payor.PayorID++;
                    }

                    db.Payors.Add(p);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }
        if (applicantCapturedData.PracticeInfoOtherLocations != null)
        {
            if (applicantCapturedData.PracticeInfoOtherLocations.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (var p in OtherAddressList)
                {
                    otheraddresses.City = p.City;
                    otheraddresses.Fax = p.Fax;
                    otheraddresses.Phone = p.Phone;
                    otheraddresses.State = p.State;
                    otheraddresses.Street = p.Street;
                    otheraddresses.Suite = p.Suite;
                    otheraddresses.ZipCode = p.ZipCode;
                    otheraddresses.AppID = newid;
                    otheraddresses.ID = p.ID;

                    if (otheraddresses.ID <= c)
                    {
                        otheraddresses.ID = otheraddresses.ID++;
                    }

                    db.PracticeInfoOtherLocations.Add(p);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }

        if (applicantCapturedData.EPrescribe != null)
        {
            if (applicantCapturedData.EPrescribe.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (var p in Eprescribelist)
                {
                    eprescribe.EPrescribeOptions = p.EPrescribeOptions;
                    eprescribe.ID = p.ID;

                    p.ApplicantCapturedData_ID = newid;

                    if (eprescribe.ID <= c)
                    {
                        eprescribe.ID = eprescribe.ID++;
                    }

                    db.EPrescribes.Add(p);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }

        if (applicantCapturedData.TaxNPITaxonomy != null)
        {
            if (applicantCapturedData.TaxNPITaxonomy.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (var t in taxlist)
                {
                    tax.GroupNPI = t.GroupNPI;
                    tax.Notes = t.Notes;
                    tax.TaxID = t.TaxID;
                    tax.TaxNPITaxonomyID = t.TaxNPITaxonomyID;
                    tax.Taxonomy = t.TaxID;
                    t.ApplicantCapturedData_ID = newid;

                    if (tax.TaxNPITaxonomyID <= c)
                    {
                        tax.TaxNPITaxonomyID = tax.TaxNPITaxonomyID++;
                    }

                    db.TaxNPITaxonomies.Add(t);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(applicantCapturedData);
}
```

Comment: silly question but when u update the form, the changes are reflected in database, but not showing up in index view?

Comment: it will be helpful if u posted your controller actions and how you save it to database

Comment: @HastaTamang - yes, in the form it shows in db, but index view isn't showing the change.

Comment: @HastaTamang - see update in question.

Comment: In your DbContext file do you override db.SaveChanges() ?  Is it there that the edit assignment is taking place?

Comment: Show us your "onClick" handler. How is that posting to your action?

Comment: @HastaTamang - For db.saveChanges() it's virtual. I tried going to implementation and it says symbol has no implementations.

Comment: In that case, i suggest you put a breakpoint and investigate when you get the data from Database to Controller to View. See how your UpdatedBy changed from new to old user

Comment: @Jasen - it's the standard kendo onclick that's used in the form.

Comment: I do not think the form is passing UpdateBy property to your contoller. Anyhow your UpdateBy changes are reflected in your database correct?

Comment: @HastaTamang - I don't think it's changing UpdateBy.  I have a breakpoint in the applicantController, Edit(applicantCapturedData), and it's not showing a change in UpdateBy after it comes back from the form. I'm not clear where that's supposed to happen.

Comment: I don't see change in db data for UpdateBy.

Comment: Model.ADAccount can u check if this has the current logged in user value. Sorry @Michele I'm lost what might be wrong

Comment: @HastaTamang - Yes, when I'm in the form, the Model.ADAccount is me. I've checked my breakpoint.

Comment: I see can you check your UpdatedBy is passed to the Controller on POST? It might be the Form is not passing this value. As @Jasen said might have to look into that form

Comment: ApplicantController, Edit(ApplicantCapturedData) is where the post from the form goes to and by there, we've lost UpdateBy already.